# Keyboard shortcuts without x11

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I had found the solution a while ago, but now I google for hours and can't find it. 
So, the question is: how to set up a keyboard shortcut in linux (eg. ubuntu) without running X-server?
I have home server with ubuntu on it, and I want to run scripts, when I press multimedia keys on keyboard. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Noteworthy: [keebie](https://github.com/robinuniverse/Keebie) (via [unix.SE#588498](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/588498/17409))

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux users have the `bash` shell.  You can edit your `.inputrc` file to make it reinterpret a sequence of characters (which your multimedia keys *may* send) into a command-string.  That is called a key binding.

To see whether this is doable, you first have to find what your keyboard sends for one of those keys.  You can do this by running

```
cat -v
```

(which makes special characters show in a printable form), and pressing (and releasing!) <kbd>control/V</kbd> just before pressing the multimedia key which you want to bind.

If your keyboard does send usable strings, the next step is to modify your `.inputrc` file to make suitable key bindings. The `bash` manual's section [8.3 Readline Init File](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File.html) provides more information.  There are various other sources such as the detailed descriptions in [Linux From Scratch](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lfs/LFS-BOOK-6.1.1-HTML/chapter07/inputrc.html).

Comment: Nice idea, but to run bash, I need to login in tty. So, I have to physically enter my username and password (I have no monitor connected). Am I right? btw, this keyboard I use, is actually a remote which behaves like a keyboard. It only has media keys ;)

Comment: You could (in principle) setup a special user whose name is easy to type, with no password, that runs in a restricted shell (allow only certain commands).  But without a monitor to test with, that sounds challenging to implement.

Answer (score 0):

`actkbd` can run arbitrary programs on Linux key events.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: "Currently only the following platforms are supported: Linux 2.6.x" -- :(

Comment: @Raphael linux 5.12 is a sort of linux 2.6.x ;)